# asp.net 4.5 web forms and datacontext dispose

Tags: asp.net, webforms, model-binding

I've been going through a couple of tutorials and videos by microsoft covering the enhancements to asp.net 4.5 web forms. One thing that I'm noticing is that none of them dispose of the datacontext.  I'm wondering if the new modelbinding namespace causes the page to automatically call dispose on any datacontexts it has, if the videos/tutorials are incomplete, or if something else is going on?  Here's an example of some code shown in the wingtip toy store tutorial.  Notice it doesn't have a using statement around the datacontext.  Does it automatically get disposed when the page life cycle ends?

**Update**

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvMyAccount" OnCallingDataMethods="MyAccount_CallingDataMethods" SelectMethod="GetAll" DeleteMethod="DeleteItem" ItemType="MyAccountHelper" >
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="AccountCode" HeaderText="Account Id" SortExpression="AccountCode" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind

```
public partial class MyAccounts : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void MyAccount_CallingDataMethods(object sender, CallingDataMethodsEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DataMethodsObject = new MyAccountBL();
    }
}
```

BL File

```
public class MyAccountBL : IDisposable
    {
        MyModel db = new MyModel();

        public IQueryable<MyAccountHelper> GetAll()
        {
             return db.MyAccounts;
        }

        private bool disposedValue = false;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposedValue)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    db.Dispose();
                }
            }
            this.disposedValue = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide us minimal verifiable code snippet .

Comment: @Eldho Please check the update

Comment: Whenever the  `MyAccountBL ` is disposed everything inside this will be disposed including your dbcontext